# Animation in Uiscrollview with a button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have tried the iCarousel, and add it to my project. I was able to put images. Now I'm trying to implement a method, that when the button was clicked the carousel will rotate. 
I've tried this code:

```
- (IBAction) spinButton:(id)sender
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:carousel
                             cache:YES];
    [spinButton removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

But it seems to be that only the carousel view is animating.

Comment: Are u want to create like wise to implement  ?http://youtu.be/v5bhkCXKxTs

Comment: Hi sir @neonsamuel, i want to implement a button to be a able to spin the iCarousel like the link you've shown me.

Comment: Yes. But I need to implement the spin method, which I can't make the carousel do.

Comment: Hello, Can you want to set the button into the carousel view am i right going or not?

Comment: I've already set the button in the view sir, but doesn't have the implementation on the spin yet.

Comment: Now that button you want to spin that view am i correct

Comment: i want to spin the carousel sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following two method to changes aries may be your problem being solve by this,

```
-(void)TappedButton:(UIButton *)sender{

    UIView *view=[carousel itemViewAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:view cache:YES];
    //    [spinButton removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
}             
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"]] autorelease];
//      label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds] autorelease];
//      label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//      label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
//      label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
//        
//        [view addSubview:label];

        UIButton *buttonForDisplay = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: view.bounds] autorelease];
        buttonForDisplay.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        [buttonForDisplay setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonForDisplay.titleLabel.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        [buttonForDisplay addTarget:self action:@selector(TappedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonForDisplay bringSubviewToFront:view];
        buttonForDisplay.tag = index;

///        view.tag=index;
        [view addSubview:buttonForDisplay];


    }
    else
    {
        label = [[view subviews] lastObject];
    }

    //set label
//  label.text = [[items objectAtIndex:index] stringValue];

    return view;
}
```

**EDIT**
This method thru you  can catch the reference of the carousel view.

```
- (UIView *)itemViewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

**Edit with Animation**

```
UIViewController *nextViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] autorelease];
nextViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 3.5;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:NO];
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: wow. nice. thanks sir. how am I going to spin it like a kcaTransitionPush animation, with longer duration?

Comment: thanks sir :) how did you do that? :) how am I going to spin it like a kcaTransitionPush animation, with longer duration?

Comment: sir how about the spinning the carousel vertically? with array of images?